# Rubyでアルゴリズムを学ぶのに適した書籍やサイトを教えてください

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

はじめまして、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

以下質問となるので、お答えいただければ幸いです。

例えばなのですが、15枚の絵札から5枚のカードを引くプログラムを書いてください.
といった問題をRuby言語で学習する場合に適した書籍、サイトなどあるのでしょうか？？

上記のようなテスト行い、基準点に達することができず、アルゴリズムの学習をよりしなければと強く思いググっみたのですが、あまり適したサイトを見つけることができなかった為、こちらで質問させていただきます。

できればRubyの言語でアルゴリズムの学習ができればと考えております。

Comment: メタでの議論 [「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応 - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/10492)

Comment: 上記コメントの回答にあるように、宣伝や情報の陳腐化の問題がありますが、主にRubyで書かれた書籍に「プログラマ脳を鍛える数学パズル シンプルで高速なコードが書けるようになる70問」（https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798142456）があります。ただ、話題が少し数学寄りかもしれません。

Comment: @Manyama 票を入れたいのでコメントの内容を回答にしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

アルゴリズムを学ぶのに適した書籍はたくさんあるのですが、
とりわけRubyでと指定されると少ない気がします。
だからと言って、別の言語で解説している書籍をわざわざ
Rubyに置き換えるのも面倒なので、主にRubyで書かれた書籍を
紹介します。

「プログラマ脳を鍛える数学パズル シンプルで高速なコードが書けるようになる70問」
（http://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798142456）
→コードが載っているだけでなく、対話も交えているので読みやすいと思います。
　また、一問一問の量が多くないので、時間が空いている時にさっと読めます。

（Rubyで書かれた書籍でアルゴリズムにも言及している書籍）

「Ruby②」
（http://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798118000）
→第７章でアルゴリズムにふれています。

「Rubyによる情報科学入門」
（http://www.kindaikagaku.co.jp/information/kd0362.htm）
→題名からは分かりませんが、アルゴリズムの書籍と言えるのではないでしょうか？
　演習が豊富で、かなり数学寄りの書籍。

（おまけ）
その他の言語(C,C++,Javaが主)によるアルゴリズムに関する書籍
【基礎的なことが書いてある書籍】
②初心者向け
「プログラミングの宝箱　アルゴリズムとデータ構造」
（http://www.sbcr.jp/products/4797324198.html?sku=4797324198）
③中級者向け
「アルゴリズムクイックリファレンス」
（http://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873114286/）
【プロコンっぽい書籍】
①超初心者向け
「オンラインジャッジではじめるC/C++プログラミング入門」
（https://book.mynavi.jp/ec/products/detail/id=25382）
③中級者向け
「プログラミングコンテスト攻略のためのアルゴリズムとデータ構造」
（https://book.mynavi.jp/ec/products/detail/id=35408）
「世界で闘うプログラミング力を鍛える150問 トップIT企業のプログラマになるための本」
（https://book.mynavi.jp/ec/products/detail/id=22752）
「プログラミングコンテストチャレンジブック [第2版]」
（https://book.mynavi.jp/ec/products/detail/id=22672）
「最強最速アルゴリズマー養成講座」
（http://www.sbcr.jp/products/4797367171.html）
【パズル】
③中級者向け
続ナノピコ教室
（http://www.kyoritsu-pub.co.jp/bookdetail/9784320025417）

Answer (score 2):

範囲が広すぎないしは主観的のクローズモデ対象になりそうな内容ですが・・・

アルゴリズムとは「計算方法」であるため、言語によらず共通なものです。
「アルゴリズム解説本」というのを必要とする読者は、言語を問わないので多そうですが
「アルゴリズムを Ruby で解く本」はごく限られた読者にしか必要とされない、
とオイラは思うわけです。
購読層のパイが明らかに小さそうな本は最初から出版されません。無いものねだりな気がします。

あと、書籍にせよ web page にせよ、各個人に向いてる向いてないが必ずあります。
オイラにとってわかりやすかった書籍が、他の人にもわかりやすいかと問われれば No です。

雑談系掲示板でも「私にとってわかりやすい書籍を紹介してください」だと盛り上がりません。
「あなた自身にとってわかりやすかった書籍を勝手に紹介してください」ならば盛り上がるでしょう。
でもどちらの質問も SO 的には NG です。

（目的）なにか解きたい問題があって、
（手段）それを解く計算方法を算出する・理解する
のなら良いのですが、目的と手段が逆転していませんか？
その辺を間違えるとただの「お勉強のためのお勉強」となってつまらないこと必至です。
アルゴリズムなんて、必要になったときに検索して見つけりゃ十分です。

SO においては「答えの無い・出しようの無い質問」はあまり好まれません。
提示の例題を実装しようとして、こんなふうに考えたが、こんな感じでうまくいかない、
どう改善すればいいでしょうか？という質問なら SO の rubyist たちが突っ込んでくれるでしょう。

Comment: 774RR様

確かにおっしゃる通りと考えます。ご指摘ありがとうございました。
現在プログラミングを初めて5ヶ月程度で、初めて触れた言語がRubyなのでRubyを土台にアルゴリズムに対する認識や、論理的思考力を鍛えていければと考え、今回このような質問をいたしました。

現在Swiftにも手を出しはじめていますので、なおのことC言語に対する理解を深めてみようと考えます。

今回はご指導ありがとうございました。

失礼致します。